# Don't show empty categories in classified style

Tags: qgis, symbology, rendering, categorized-renderer

I have a geojson file containing line and polygon features.

I want to render them according to the field `Feature Type` which contains different types. When I use categorized symbology, it creates also categories which contain no elements. I think this is because some categories are only contained in the line feature layer, and some are only in the polygon layer.

Is there a way I can use categorized symbology, but leave out these empty categories?

[image]

Comment: You could delete them manually, if that is feasible.

Answer (score 1):

**Delete the empty categories in the Symbology panel**

Select the category you want to delete, and click the minus button below.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can easily switch those off in the print composer/layout view legend if that's the issue. When you add a legend just turn off auto update and delete the empty rows.

Otherwise, you might consider switching to a different legend style.